# Cloudfoundry & composer with basic auth protected repositories

Tags: composer-php, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I would like to deploy my app onto a Cloudfoundry node. Using composer for dependency management.

Now there is one repository with private packages, which is secured by basic auth (Example https://composer.example.com).

```
"repositories": [{
  "type": "composer",
  "url": "https://composer.example.com"
}]
```

By default, i'm using a `auth.json` with the needed credentials, and composer would use it.

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "composer.example.com": {
            "username": "max",
            "password": "mustermann"
        }
    }
}
```

But, pushing my app to a Cloudfoundry node, composer gets executed and will fail when it comes to include the private packages.

`The 'https://composer.example.com/the/package-1.7.3.zip' URL required authentication. You must be using the interactive console to authenticate`

Updating my dependencies locally works like a charm, deploying my app with capistrano for exmple, works as well. But cloudfoundry in some way does not recognize the `auth.json`.

Any hint or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you open a github issue against the PHP buildpack?  I'm pretty sure there's a bug here which is causing composer to not see your auth.json file.  https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack

Comment: @DanielMikusa seems that you're right. Somehow the composer.json and composer.lock files get moved into the root, but the auth.json not. So composer can't see that file... Will open a issue there. Thx.